# How to set parent height to child height or viewport height depending on which one is bigger?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a layout like this,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class = 'parent'>
            <div class = 'header'></div>
            <div class = 'child'></div>
            <div class = 'footer'></div>
        </div>
    <body>
<html>
```

The child content is variable, it might be `300px` or `800px` in height. Assuming the **viewport** is `600px`, **header** and **footer** are `50px`.

**A :** I require the parent height to become `600px` i.e. the viewport height when child is `300px` and the footer pushed to the bottom of the page.

**B :** I require the parent height to become `900px ( Header + Child + Footer )` and the content becoming scrollable when the child is `800px`

I can accomplish A and B separately is variety of ways, but cannot come up with a way to combine both.

To do **A :**

```
html, body {
    height : 100%
}

.parent {
    height : 100%;
    display : flex;
}

.header { 
    height : 50px;
}

.child {
    flex-grow : 1;
}

.footer {
    height : 50px;
}
```

To do **B:**

```
.header {
    height : 50px;
}

.footer {
    height : 50px;
}
```

The height of the viewport and the variable heights of the child are given only to clarify the question, in my case I would like to support all viewport heights and any child height.

**Javascript solution**, using along with method **B** : ( I have to use css )

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0];
if(parent.clientHeight < window.innerHeight) {
    parent.style.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking forward to [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/DomeTune/5qqw1kzy/)?

Comment: @DomeTune This example doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Ah oke, i thought you want a fixed footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to create a sticky footer, i.e. a footer that "sticks" to the bottom of the viewport when there isn't enough content to fill the viewport.

For that you're missing two things. First, your `.parent` element needs `flex-direction: column;` (`row` is the default), and second, it needs `min-height: 100vh;`. The `vh` unit [is supported in all current browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh).

In the example below I've thrown in an expanding `<summary>`/`<details>` box just to demonstrate that it works.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

p { font-size: 32px; }
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='header'></div>
  <div class='child'>
    <details>
      <summary>Expand</summary>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec bibendum, sem quis viverra fermentum, velit libero vestibulum quam, in consectetur purus massa vel velit. Cras interdum massa lobortis diam malesuada posuere. Nunc sollicitudin massa at erat tristique iaculis. Mauris lacinia facilisis pulvinar. Donec congue sodales risus, vel fermentum urna ullamcorper in. Aenean a posuere augue. Cras a viverra arcu. Ut a lobortis mauris. Proin ac rutrum erat. Duis at tempus risus, id maximus magna. Maecenas tempor commodo lacus sed rhoncus. In scelerisque sem interdum elit sagittis sodales ut id elit. Curabitur porta, quam vitae iaculis rhoncus, metus ante commodo quam, vitae dictum lectus ex sed orci.</p>
    </details>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give parent a `min-height: 100vh;`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header,
.footer {
  flex-grow: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='header'>Header</div>
  <div class='child'>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
    <p>a line</p>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There you go, need some flexbox do stretch them

Answer (score 0):

AVAVT's answer is correct, I am also posting this answer if someone doesn't wish to use `vh` because currently compatibility is poor.

```
html, body {
    height : 100%
}

.parent {
    min-height : 100%;
    display : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
}

.header { 
    height : 50px;
}

.child {
    flex-grow : 1;
}

.footer {
    height : 50px;
}
```

Comment: Browser support for `vh` is actually not poor. Quite the contrary. `vmax` isn't supported by IE / Edge, but other viewport percentage units are good. http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport

Comment: vh compatibility is still poor atleast looking at the Indian scenario, with just 42% support http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units. Probably because mobile support lacking.